# Число 0.00004507 записывает в базу как 4.484E-5

Tags: php, sql

В базе колонка с типом: **varchar(50)**, я в эту колонку записываю текст "**0.00004507**"  а в базу пишет такое: "**4.484E-5**".

Как убрать это форматирование?

Пробовал подставлять в эту колонку **в начало и конец буквы**, (думал не будет форматировать если явно строка будет) - но оно записывает так: "**а 4.484E-5 а**".

Нашел кусок, где преобразуется это число, это не база изменяет, а пхп.

```
$amount =  0.00000194 * 1;
var_dump($amount);
// Выводит: float(1.94E-6)
```

Сделал через number_format, и все правильно теперь.

Comment: Записываете как именно ? простой тест показывает, что MySQL такого не делает http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/07c70e/1 значит это делает ваш язык. не видя код невозможно сказать, что именно приводит к такому результату

Comment: Представим на секунду что в базу пишет именно **"4.484E-5"**. А когда вы читаете из базы, результат все еще такой же? Или форматируется обратно в **"0.00004507"**?

Comment: **Это** не может делать **то**. То, что Вы описываете, просто не может происходить.

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, код, который отвечает за запись в бвзу.

Comment: @SergeyShitikov перепутал, в базу пишется уже готовая строка 1.94E-6, которую пхп генерит

Answer (score 0):

Поставьте тип столбца float в вашей таблице